# matplotlib TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble understanding this error as this is the first time I've used matplotlib. I'm trying to to calculate the time it takes to sort random lists and then plot that information on a graph. The only thing I can think of is I'm somehow returning a the function wrapper rather than the total_time. Here is my code.

```
import functools
import time
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot


def sort_timer(func):
    """
    Timer function that counts how many seconds it takes the decoration function to run, in this case the sort functions
    described above. Returns the number of seconds using the time module.
    :param func:
    :return total_time:
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Calculates the total time a sort function runs.
        :return:
        """

        total_time = None

        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()

        total_time = end_time - start_time

        return total_time

    return

@sort_timer
def bubble_sort(a_list):
  """
  Sorts a_list in ascending order
  """
  for pass_num in range(len(a_list) - 1):
    for index in range(len(a_list) - 1 - pass_num):
      if a_list[index] > a_list[index + 1]:
        temp = a_list[index]
        a_list[index] = a_list[index + 1]
        a_list[index + 1] = temp


@sort_timer
def insertion_sort(a_list):
  """
  Sorts a_list in ascending order
  """
  for index in range(1, len(a_list)):
    value = a_list[index]
    pos = index - 1
    while pos >= 0 and a_list[pos] > value:
      a_list[pos + 1] = a_list[pos]
      pos -= 1
    a_list[pos + 1] = value


def compare_sorts(bubble_sort, insertion_sort):
    """
    Compares the time it takes to run sorting functions of any type. Returns the time calculated using the time
    function.
    :return total_time:
    """

    # establishing counter and while loop to run the sorts
    counter = 0
    bubble_sort_time = []
    insertion_sort_time = []

    while counter < 10:
        # list size counter, will increase by 1000 each iteration
        list_size = 1000

        # random list generator
        list_1 = random.sample(range(1, 10000), list_size)
        list_2 = list(list_1)

        # Calling the functions and appending the results of sort_timer to each list
        bubble_sort_time.append(sort_timer(bubble_sort(list_1)))
        insertion_sort_time.append(sort_timer(insertion_sort(list_2)))

        # incrementing list_size and counter
        list_size += 1000
        counter += 1

    # matplot of the resulting data, displaying it on a graph
    pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], bubble_sort_time, 'go--', linewidth=2, label='Bubble Sort')
    pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], insertion_sort_time, 'ro--', linewidth=2, label='Insertion Sort')
    pyplot.xlabel("Number of Sorts Tested")
    pyplot.ylabel("Time in Seconds")
    pyplot.legend(loc='upper left')
    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. It is your responsibility, before asking, to: 1) try to *read* and *understand* the error message (*where* in your code is it coming from?); 2) try to solve the problem yourself; 3) try to isolate the problematic code and figure out what is *needed to reproduce the problem*; 4) show a minimal, complete example along with the [complete, corresponding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: Anyway, there are multiple problems here. To start: decorators should *return* the decorated result (`return wrapper` in your case). But there isn't really a good reason to use a decorator here; instead, have `sort_timer` accept the function as an argument (along with the list to sort), and have it just be an ordinary function.